# How do I populate my SQL table with values in excel via R

Tags: r

Trying to use R to update my SQL table, but how do I automate the process if I have an excel sheet full of values that I need to change?

```
D_MASTER_UPDATE_LINE <- "UPDATE D_MASTER
                                SET
                                CLASS = 'A'
                                WHERE id = '26'"
      
D_MASTER_UPDATE <- (DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = D_MASTER_UPDATE_LINE ))
```

So the above works well in updating 1 row of CLASS where the id is 26

However, suppose I have an excel sheet full of IDs and CLASS; how should I use R to interface with the excel sheet to fill the values into the SQL table?

```
master_read<- read_excel("D_MASTER.xlsx", sheet = "D_MASTER")
  
for(i in master_read$id) {
    DAM_UPDATE_LINE <- paste0(
      "UPDATE D_MASTER
      SET 
      CLASS = ? 
      WHERE id = ?"
    )
  }
```

I am stuck at the above script... what should I populate in id and CLASS so that it updates the entire SQL table with the values from my excel sheet of master_read?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop we can iterate over each row and create the query dynamically.

```
master_read<- read_excel("D_MASTER.xlsx", sheet = "D_MASTER")

for(i in seq(nrow(master_read))) {
  DAM_UPDATE_LINE <- sprintf("UPDATE D_MASTER
                            SET
                            CLASS = '%s'
                            WHERE id = '%s'", master_read$class[i], master_read$id[i])
  D_MASTER_UPDATE <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = DAM_UPDATE_LINE)
}
```